# R Notebook and SQL Code in Output html file

Tags: r, rnotebook

I am running R Notebook with sql code, but the SQL code is not displayed in the final html output file

````
```{sql connection=db}
SQL QUERY

```
````

The R Code is displayed as usually.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Looking for a solution

Comment: The was a bug. It was fixed in the latest version of RStudio.